# Cannot find protocol declaration

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

Cannot find protocol declaration for MyPocketAppDelegate
This was an error message showed when an application is done what will be the problem ca ay one help me to solve it.

Comment: How are you declaring it? And what is the exact error you are being shown?

Comment: #import MyPocketAppDelegate.h                                                          Is n't it right

Comment: The exact error is  "Cannot find protocol declaration for MyPocketAppDelegate"

Comment: Isn't `MyPocketAppDelegate` your application delegate class?

Comment: yes it is error is shown in the following part  @interface Paypal : UIViewController<MyPocketAppDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say `MyPocketAppDelegate` is your application delegate class, it cannot be adopted or conformed. Protocols and classes are two different things.

You should remove it from protocol list.

```
@interface Paypal : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot deepak it worked I'm new to iphone programming so dont know about the codes correctly

Comment: +1, quite good, it is appDelegate class not a protocol.couldn't see this in question.